# How to remove a hidden input from a div

Tags: jquery, html

I want to remove a hidden input when a 'Remove' button or in other words the delete function is called, but problem is that with code below it does not remove the input, how can I get the correct input to be removed depending on the file name which is removed? Below is the code where it removes the correct file name but does not remove the hidden input (For testing I changed it to text input):

```
  function stopImageUpload(success, imageID, imagefilename){

      var result = '';
      imagecounter++;

      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span class="imagemsg'+imagecounter+'">The file was uploaded successfully</span>';   
            $('.hiddenimg').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<input type="hidden" name="imgid[]" id="'+imageID+'" value="' + imageID + '" />');
            $('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '<button type="button" class="deletefileimage" data-imageID="'+imageID+'"  data-image_file_name="' + imagefilename + '">Remove</button><br/><hr/></div>');
         }

 var _imagecounter = imagecounter;

    $('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).find(".deletefileimage").on("click", function(event) {
        jQuery.ajax("deleteimage.php?imagefilename=" + $(this).attr('data-image_file_name')).done(function(data) {
            $(".imagemsg" + _imagecounter).html(data);
        });

        $(this).parent().remove();
        $(".hiddenimg").parent().remove();
    });

          return true;   
    }
```

Below is the file input form:

```
var $fileImage = $("<form action='imageupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target_image' onsubmit='return imageClickHandler(this);' class='imageuploadform' >" + 
"<p class='imagef1_upload_form'><label>" + 
"Image File: <input name='fileImage' type='file' class='fileImage' /></label><br/><br/><label class='imagelbl'>" + 
"<input type='submit' name='submitImageBtn' class='sbtnimage' value='Upload' /></label>" + 
"<input type='hidden' class='numimage' name='numimage' value='" + GetFormImageCount() + "' />" +</p>
"</p><p class='imagemsg'></p><p class='listImage'></p>" +
"<iframe class='upload_target_image' name='upload_target_image' src='/' style='width:0px;height:0px;border:0px;solid;#fff;'></iframe></form>");
```

The hidden input is placed in a div in another form and the reason it is in another form is because the form above will be nested into the form below and if I included the hidden input in above form, then I will have problem using $_POST to post the values from the hidden input in a nested form:

```
<form id="QandA" action="" method="post">
<div class='hiddenimg'></div>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do. Which element do you want to remove? I see you're removing the `parent` of `.hiddenimg`, which would remove the `form`. What, specifically do you want to remove? And when what is clicked, do you want it removed?

Comment: @matthewpavkov In jquery in success = 1 brackets, `.listImage` section, you will see where it shows filenames and remove button. Now for each filename it contains it's own remove button and hidden input (line below is where it displays hidden input), now what I want is if the remove button is clicked for a particular filename, I want the filename and remove button to be removed which it does but I also want the hidden input associated with the filename in the `hiddenimg` div to be removed

Comment: Where is the `hiddenimg` div/form at in relation to the image and delete button? If you could provide clearer HTML, that would be a help. The `$fileImage` doesn't seem to come into play here, or does it?

Comment: @matthewpavkov It is at the bottom of the question. If that is where I am going wrong then what do I need to do to correct it. The hidden input is placed in the `#QandA' form, a seperate form than the image file input form

Comment: I see that the `input` element has an `id` attribute, so is there a way you can get the `id` value of the hidden input element?  If so, you can just use `document.getElementById("imageId").remove()`.  That will remove the element.

Comment: I don't see a `#QandA` form. Can you give us the HTML that's actually in the DOM when this is all rendered? It would be really easy to answer your question then. We need to see the hierarchy of the HTML to determine how you can use jQuery to do what you want.

Comment: @matthewpavkov sorry I did a typeo in SO, it is suppose to be `#QandA' for form at bottom of question.

Comment: @icanc so to make sure, in jquery should it simply be `$("#imageid").remove();`? Do I need to include a `this`?

Comment: So you want to remove a hidden div `.hiddenimg` from the form `#QandA`? Just add one more line in your click handler `$('#QandA .hiddenimg').remove()`

Comment: @matthewpavkov The hidden input inside the `.hiddenimg` div. The hidden input is appended into the div

Comment: @user1881090 Yes, `$("#imageid").remove();` should also work.

Comment: `$('.hiddenimg input).remove()` will remove an input in the `.hiddenimg` div.

Comment: @icanc `$("#imageID").remove();` did not remove the hidden input(s)

Comment: @matthewpavkov This removes the hidden inputs but I need the correct hidden inputs to be removed, depending on the file name removed. At the moment it deletes all hidden inputs in the div